# Oracle Database Capacity Planning

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle12c, database-performance, database-partitioning

Just want to know if there is a formula I can use how to estimate database storage size needed based on estimated number of records and data types of those records that will be stored.

Are there available or shared spreadsheets I can use in order to be able to accurately have an LO estimate of size of storage needed?

We are using Oracle 12c

Comment: From Oracle's Database Administrator's Guide: [Capacity Planning for Database Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema006.htm#ADMIN11621).

Comment: Thanks for this @GilbertLeBlanc. But is there a way to do this if you're not a database admin? I mean like a formula developers can use

Comment: You can get a rough estimate for each table.  First, multiply the number of rows times the length of each row in bytes.  Next, calculate the primary index space by multiplying the number of rows times the length of the primary index in bytes.  Do the same for all other indexes.  Add the products together, and multiply by 1.1 to account for table and index overhead,